# Why npm pack includes 'node_modules' folder

Tags: npm, package, node-modules, rollup, pack

I've successfully created a react app package using rollup and packed using npm pack.

Question is why library includes node_modules folder as well, where other libraries don't.

I would appreciate your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfoY0.png)